# upgrade hibernate to 4.1.3 breaks our code

Tags: hibernate

We started getting the exception "Found two representations of same collection: models.CompanyDbo.users"

relevant code for that field is

```
//code inside the CompanyDbo bean....
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
private List<UserDbo> users = new ArrayList<UserDbo>();

//code inside the UserDbo mapping back to Company
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable=false)
private CompanyDbo company;

//code inside the controller (and the failure happens on commit)....
CompanyDbo companyDbo = new CompanyDbo();
companyDbo.setSoftwareType(softwareType);
user.setManager(user);
user.setRole(Role.ADMIN);
//NEXT TWO lines set both ends of the association...(not that it is completely necessary since there is only one FK really in the UserDbo table).
user.setCompany(companyDbo);
companyDbo.addUser(user); 

JPA.em().persist(companyDbo);
JPA.em().persist(user);
JPA.em().flush();
```

What do I need to change to get this working?  I have read some people have cascade on but I don't have cascade on anywhere.

Comment: Based on my previous findings on the project I was working on, if User is a property of CompanyDbo, then by default configuration it would not need to be explicitly persisted, unless it was configured to be stored separately, which is not a normal practice.

Comment: are you sure you didn't have cascade setup?  as I explicitly am not using cascade which it what causes that to occur.  (I personally find cascades to be more trouble then they are worth and get into some nasty debug isssue with those settings).

Comment: You are right, I had a default cascade for "save-update" in hibernate-mapping.xml. So for that project, the default was to use cascade.

Comment: yeah, I avoid that like the plague as projects tend to get into circular cascades which cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out calling flush and then commit and commit calls flush which fails being called the second time(the session is the same instance).  Maybe this is a 4.1.3 bug or something.

hmmm, then modifying the code to this fails at the second flush call(and this should be allowed though it doesn't flush much)...

```
JPA.em().persist(companyDbo);
JPA.em().persist(user);
JPA.em().flush();
JPA.em().flush(); //now this fails
```

Dean